# RS485 RTS on pin

Tags: gpio, serial

I accidentally connected the wrong pin (GPIO21) as RTS to uart to MAX3485 IC on my PCB. Is it possible to control this pin via software for half duplex data flow for RS485?
It only needs to read modbus registers at a low baud rate(9600).